# Get Text Area current line length using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textarea

I wanted to validate Text Area current line when user press enter key. When current line length is 0 it should return false and else return true. Can this be done in JQuery easily?

Comment: @Tushar What do you mean?

Comment: `trim` will remove trailing spaces

Comment: @Tushar I only wanted to count current line character length in a text area

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
<textarea id="txtArea">
    </textarea>
```

jQuery

```
 $("#txtArea").on('keypress',function(event){
        var _getEventKey =   event.keyCode
        if(_getEventKey ==13){
        if($("#txtArea").val().trim().length ==0){
        alert('No text')
        }
        else{
        alert($("#txtArea").val().length);
        }
        }
    })
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30dufw9o/1/)